# 1966 ford 3400 tractor 3cyl deisel

Tags: engine

I have a 1966 ford tractor witch needs a seal kit, can I start the motor sum how to make it will run for a second or two . I do not know if it runs. the injection pump needs to be reseal

Comment: What seal kit? Hub bearing, gearbox?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you clarify your question for us? What's holding it back from running? What is the "seal kit" for ... I get it, "sealing" ... but what is it sealing? Oil? Diesel Fuel? Compression? I'm not really sure what you're asking.